# Scraping Data from Client Side JS with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, post, web-scraping, python-requests

How do i begin to scrape a webpage with button click that only shows the output in Client Side(output seen only in Chrome Dev Tools-response Tab) 
I am aware of using Selenium or Phantom JS but I am against both due to shortage of memory

I am also aware of POST requests but sometimes POST requests give all data except the data that is only visible through Chrome Dev Tools(response Tab) .

Eg Scenario : Suppose there is a download button in a page which performs a POST and then a GET to retreive a .PDF file. The result of POST contains a Dynamic ID (plus some additional HTML Data).The ID is then attached with hostname of URL to retrieve the .PDF File. However this Dynamic ID is nowhere to be seen in source code and is generated on the fly(Think .jsf Pages which have a Client ID for example) and visible only in response tab of Chrome Dev Tools in the client side. The POST Data retrieves all  HTML Data except for this dynamic ID.

How do go about this using POST request of Python without going for Selenium

Comment: This is a vague question.  Please clarify the constraints more.  Also give as many details as possible.  Also, what kind of date are you scraping?  It sounds like you are just wanting a web scraping / spidering tool or possibly utilization of something akin to Burpsuite?

Comment: @Fallenreaper : The constraint is already specified in question. It appears only the client side (Chrome Dev Tools Network Tab) .The data can be an Dynamic changing ID for instance

Comment: Give the website link to guide you better

Comment: @Akshay In your example scenario, you are actually wrong.  All the information obtained in the network tab is *just* the network information for the request.  Tools external to a browser can easily catalogue that information for you, with better means to sort through it and automate crawling the website for additional information.  If sounds like you are requiring a the Browser Dev Tools where you should think outside the box more as to "what app can i use to get all this network traffic"

Comment: @Fallenreaper : My apologies its actually response TAB. But the network tab provides a hint of whats happening with the server that we can emulate to get something if I am right.Eg POST and GET requests

Comment: @SmashGuy :  Sorry cant provide it due to a NDA